# Xbee can send from arduino to XCTU, but not the other way around

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I have two arduinos that I would like to use to communicate with two xbees. I programmed both xbees with the xbee explorer breakout boards in XCTU, and got them to communicate on XCTU. They are XB24Cs, with the Zigbee function set, both on the same PAN ID, one as a Coordinator and one as a router, not on API mode. When I put the router on an xbee shield on an arduino, I run a program on the arduino that should allow me to communcate both ways, However I can send something through the serial and have it show up on the XCTU, but anything typed in XCTU will not show up in arduino. The arduino shield is the sainsmart xbee pro shield, and I tried it both with the jumpers in USB and XBee mode, however I can only ever upload first when it is on USB mode. How can I make communication possible from the computer to the arduino?

Here is my arduino code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Xbee(2,3);

void setup() {
  Xbee.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println("test");
 delay(1000);
  if(Xbee.available()){
    Serial.println(Xbee.read());
  }
  if(Serial.available()){
    Xbee.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```